# Ruby attr_accessor not being read

Tags: ruby, chipmunk, attr-accessor

I am developing a game with Ruby using the `Gosu` and `Chipmunk` gems. I have the following class in the file named `HeroBullets.rb`:

```
require 'gosu'

class HeroBullets
  attr_accessor :y
  def initialize(window)
    @x = 20
    @y = 0
  end
end
```

I know need to access this class from another file, `Physics.rb` which handles all the `Chipmunk` code.

At the top I have:

```
require 'chipmunk'

load 'HeroBullets.rb'

class Physics
   attr_accessor :play_area 

def initialize(window)

    @hBullets = Array.new(25)
    @hBullets << HeroBullets.new(window)
    @hBullets << HeroBullets.new(window)
end
```

And further down there is:

```
  def fire_arrow(y)
    for i in 0...@hBullets.count
      @bullet = @hBullets[i]
      if(@bullet.y == y)
        @hBullets[i].active = true
      end
    end
  end
```

The Error I get is:

```
Physics.rb:112:in block in fire_arrow': undefined methody' for nil:NilClass 
(NoMethodError) from Physics.rb:110:in each' from Physics.rb:110:infire_arrow'
from FileManager.rb:90:in fireHero' from .../lib/main.rb:90:inupdate' from .../lib/main.rb:129:in `'
```

Comment: I don't see any question here. Plus, the code is still not formatted correctly.

Comment: please post exact error message you got

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that if `@hBullets` has 10 elements, `@hBullets.count` will output `10`, but `@hBullets[10]` does not work, because the index of an array starts at `0` not at `1`. The tenth element will be in `@hBullets[9]`. You get the error message because the element you are trying to access is `nil`, not because "attr_accessor is not being read".

That being said, Ruby offers much easier ways to iterate over an array. I would rewrite your code like this:

```
def fire_arrow(y)
  @hBullets.each do |bullet|
    bullet.active = true if bullet.y == y
  end
end
```

Another problem with your code is that you initialize a new array like this:

```
@hBullets = Array.new(25)
```

This creates an array with 25 elements that are all `nil`. You should start with an empty array instead:

```
@hBullets = Array.new
```

Or:

```
@hBullets = []
```

Comment: I tried to implement your version but the problem still persists. I realized I didn't save the edit where I pasted the error. Now its visible

Comment: I spotted another mistake in your code. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! :) My problem was solved. I'm relatively new to Ruby and its gems.

Comment: +1 for spotting the simple problem. There would b +2 for recommending `each`.